# JS OnClick event that will execute block of php codes

Tags: php, javascript, sql

Is there a way that when I click a button it will execute a bunch of php codes?

For example;

```
<input type="button" value="Submit Order" class="minibutton" **onClick="executePHP"**>
```

This button object right here if I click it this php codes will be executed.

```
    include("../includes/connect.php");
    include("../includes/generateTimestamp.php");
    include("../includes/knowthename.php");


    $pid=$_POST['submit_id'];
    $pname = $_POST['submit_name'];
    $total = $_POST['submit_total'];
    $quantity = $_POST['submit_qty'];
    $price = $_POST['submit_price'];
    $unit = $_POST['submit_unit'];
    $change = $_POST['submit_sukli'];
    $payment = $_POST['submit_payment'];
    $count = $_POST['count'];
    //explode
    $newpid = explode(";",$pid);
    $newpname = explode(";",$pname);
    $newquantity = explode(";",$quantity);
    $newprice = explode(";",$price);
    $newpriceunit = explode(";",$unit);


    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO sales (sales_date, total_price, emp_id) VALUES ('$timestamp','$total', '$employee_id')");
    mysql_query($sql);
    $id_gen = mysql_insert_id();
    $count = $count - 1;
    while($count = -1){

            $product_id = $newpid[$count];
            $product_name = $newpname[$count];
            $product_quantity = $newquantity[$count];
            $product_price = $newprice[$count];

            $sql2("INSERT INTO sales_details (sales_id,product_id,sales_qty,unit_price,net_price) VALUES ('$id_gen','$newpid[$count]','$product_quantity[$count]',
            '$product_price[$count]','$newpriceunit[$count]')");
            mysql_query($sql2);         
        }
    header('Location: prompt.php?x=5');

    }else{
        echo 'Nothing here!';
        }
```

I wanna make the onclick function as a breaker that if I click it, It will unbreak and continue to execute those bunch of codes,

If there is no way I can do that, is there other ways?

function isset won't work because the data will be lost(arrays) because the original data came from $_POST. My hope is the onclick event but i don't know how.

Please enlighten me wizzards of computer!

Comment: I would say this can likely be done with a jQuery/Ajax request  -- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only attach JavaScript to browser events. If you want to execute server-side code such as PHP, you need to make a call to the server. In your situation, forget javascript and just POST your form to your PHP page.

```
<form method="post" action="file.php">

  <!-- form inputs -->

  <input type="button" value="Submit Order" class="minibutton" />

</form>
```

then put your code in `file.php`

**Edit**

Put all your post data in a hidden form fields. Then when you click the button, it will resubmit the post data.

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="'.htmlspecialchars($key).'" value="'.htmlspecialchars($val).'" />'."\n";
}
```

If you have a multi-dimensional post array, just `serialize()` it, stick it in 1 field

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="data" value="'.htmlspecialchars(serialize($_POST)).'" />'."\n";
```

then `unserialize()` it on the other side.

```
$_POST = unserialize($_POST['data']);
```

Comment: Like I said, I cannot do a POST and get it on isset because the file data is also came from another POST method.

If I do that then all the data will be erased and it is an ARRAY.

Comment: Okay, the original data came from sales.php using POST.
The current page I'm in is checkorder.php.
I've display all the data that came from sales.php.

Now I made a button that if that button gets clicked, then it would execute a block of php to put the data in the database.

Comment: This might be the answer I'm looking for, Its my first time to encounter this serialize() function. I will read more about it and update you if this works. Thanks a lot ddlshack!

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$('.minibutton').on('click', function(e) {
    // do some ajax stuff here 
});
```

Examples: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Its a good solution but I still haven't tried ajax or jquery, I would try it in the future. I'm doing this project with the basic php and js if there is.

Answer (score 0):

If your .php needs values that comes from the clicked element, **no you dont.**
If your code is just a bunch of php on its own, irrelevant to client requests, you 
could echo it in a **js function** and call that on click.

Comment: I guess that could work but the thing is how is it okay to put a php codes inside a JS function?

I could be getting errors by this but I will try it to see if it works

Comment: actually no -- i meant you call your php -while- on server and echo a possibly produced js code BY the .php (the only thing callable by js without hitting the server) - you cannot call .php while on client's side; only a result of .php echo (js/html), just echoed in your function..